# paypal sandbox account fail

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

I am trying to create a paypal sandbox test account. I fill all the fields providing a complex password and 100USD as a balance. Still after creating and checking the profile of the account I got the error message

> We experienced some issues on our end while creating this Sandbox account. Please delete it and try again.

and the PayPal balance is 0
I've tried everything suggested on Google, nothing works! am I missing something or there is a current problem with PayPal?

Comment: The same for me.  But when I create a new Account with country US, it works. (Default for me was Switzerland)

Answer (score 2):

I'm having exactly the same issue (or almost).

I get similar errors and when I get an account created, it is unverified... Maybe it is something wrong with the Paypal Sandbox site right now.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to provision an account after trying many options, used complex password, setting to no bank account and none on credit card and filling in the optional notes it finally worked.  Hopefully that will help someone.

Comment: I would say this solution is ridiculous, but it works like a charm!

Comment: I 100% agree with that assessment.

Answer (score 0):

Right now creating a sandbox account through the developer.paypal.com (bulk or individual) works if you let it add a credit card and have a complex password. If you tell it to only create a linked bank account it comes up with that error.

Unfortunately trying to add or remove linked credit cards and bank accounts is also not working right now.