# Sandbox for PayPal all time ask me to add a credit card

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I set up correctly the sandbox accounts (seller and buyer) long time ago, until past week everything was working good, now at test into sandbox always ask me to add a credit card, if I add the new credit card info, it shows again the same form asking to add a credit card, no error or another information is shown. If I try to test without the paypal account, using the credit card payment way, after I put the info of credit card an buyer, says credit card declined. All these data are the same I used until the previous week, and it was working well. I'm using a third part cart with checkout button (REST API)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing. I think there is something wrong with Paypal sandbox environment right now (or as usual). If you want to try the payment now there is a solution.
Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128145/829055) on another question related to this issue.

But you can only use the credit in your account instead of credit card.